# What does "void f(int (*)[7]) {}" mean?

Tags: c++, pointers

Can somebody explain what does it mean?

```
void f(int (*)[7]) {}
```

Comment: While the linked question does not explicitly answer your question about your specific construct, it does give you the two tools you need for solving this, and other, questions about "what does this mean" -- the cdecl tool and the spiral rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a function definition, which can accept a pointer to an array of int with 7 size.

Declare an 7-size array, `int a[7];`, and you can pass the address of it into f, like `f(&a)`;

Check the live: http://cpp.sh/8ztz

Answer (score 7):

There is a site devoted to dealing with C gibberish and converting it to English: 
[cdecl.org](http://cdecl.org) Try it) It is convenient and sometimes even entertaining.

It states that `void f(int (*)[7])` means:  `declare f as function (pointer to array 7 of int) returning void`.

Comment: Why the downvote? Yes, the answer is the same, but I provided a useful link.

Comment: The useful link could have been a comment, no?

Comment: @juanchopanza why make a separate comment, when you can give the correct answer *and* a link to allow undestanding gibberish on ther own in the future?

Comment: @user2079303 Because there were already three correct answers? Really, there is no obligation to answer everything. I removed my answer now so this looks less ridiculous.

Comment: @juanchopanza, well, it seems that at least four people (at the moment) are not agree with you.

Answer (score 1):

It's definition of function that takes one parameter. That parameter is an unnamed pointer to array of ints.